# Getting liked pages on my facebook

Tags: android, facebook

It is possible to get liked pages from my facebook account with the facebook sdk into an android application?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, Using Graph Api.
This is the link for it.
The pages will be provided as pageIds.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/likes/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have configured your manifest file and created a Facebook app (developers.facebook.com), add the app id to your strings.xml file. You will also need to request the **user_likes** permission. Then using this code:

```
private void fetchPagesILike(){
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/me/likes/",
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

                    //create a method to handle the resopnse
                    processResponse(response);
                }
            });
    request.executeAsync();
}
```

You can easily parse the response and even make more requests using the nextPageToken since you might not get all the pages you like in one request.

It is probably worth noting that this permission requires Review by Facebook Team before your app goes LIVE!

I hope this helps!